# Implementing a linked list using C++

Tags: c++, beginner, linked-list

Any suggestions?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class node 
{       
        friend class linked;

        private:
                int data;

        public:
                node *link;
                node()
                {
                        data=0;
                        link=NULL;

                }


};
class linked
{
        public:
                node *start=NULL;
                node *ptr;
                node *temp=NULL;

                void append(int item);
                void traverse();

};

void linked::append(int item)
{       
        ptr = new node();
        ptr->data=item;
        if(start==NULL)
        {
                start=ptr;
                ptr->link=NULL;
                temp=start;


        }
        else
        {
                while(temp->link!=NULL)
                {
                     temp=temp->link;

                }
                temp->link=ptr;
                ptr->link=NULL;

         }       


}
void linked::traverse()
{       
        node *trav=start;
        while(trav!=NULL)
        {
                cout<<trav->data<<endl;
                trav=trav->link;
        }

}
int  main()
{
        int i;

        linked box;

        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
           box.append(i);

        }

        box.traverse();      
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Starting at the top

```
//any suggestions
```

Yes, plenty. But don't add that to the code.

### using namespace std;

Nearly every beginner includes this (and it's understandable because this is what they do in books).

In actual practice this is a bad idea. Never include this line in real code. The reason books include it is to save space (because each printed page costs extra). When writing real code, this will create bad habits that will bite you in the end so it is a habit you should break now.

see: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/14065)

### node class

#### protection level

There is no need to make the `node` class public. This is internal to your linked list so you should hide its implementation from other people by making it a private member class of the `linked` class.

#### style

```
class Node 
{       
        friend class linked;

        private:
                int data;

        public:
                Node *link;
                Node()
                {
                        data=0;
                        link=NULL;

                }


};
```

Small note on vertical spacing: there is way too much here. It's a small class so it does not stand out. But if you do the same thing on a bigger class it becomes hard to read. Now don't take this to the extreme and completely eliminate vertical space-- break things up into logical units.

Since we are making this class a private member of `linked` there's no need for friendship; just make everything public.

But we can improve the code by having a constructor that takes the data value and the link (if you look at your code you could use both at the same time. When writing constructors, it's preferred to use the initializer list syntax to initialize members:

```
                Node(int data, Node* link)
                    : data(data)
                    , link(link)
                {}
```

You will notice here that everything is lower case. It is relatively common to define user-defined types with an initial capital letter, while objects have an initial lower case letter. This allows you to quickly see the difference between types and objects (an important distinction in C++).

So, following this style, your code should look like this:

```
class Linked
{
    struct Node
    {
        int    data;
        Node*  next;
        Node(int data, Node* next)
            : data(data)
            , next(next)
        {}
    };

    ....
```

### linked class

```
class linked
{
        public:
                Node *start=NULL;
                Node *ptr;
                Node *temp=NULL;

                void append(int item);
                void traverse();

};
```

Not sure what all the pointers are for? OK `start` marks the start of the list (usually called head). But what are the others supposed to represent? If they are really just things you use a throw away then they can be local to the function methods and not part of the class.

You call `new` in your code. For **every** call to `new` there must be a corresponding call to `delete`. Otherwise you will leak memory (and resources). So the best place to do this is in the destructor.

Also you are missing a constructor. This means that all you member variables are likely to be undefined (this means they have random values in them. C++ (unlike Java and other languages at this level) does not do automatic initialization of variables.

see: [Why aren't pointers initialized with NULL by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1910832/14065)

So lets add the constructor and destructor

```
class Linked
{
    struct Node
    {
        int    data;
        Node*  next;
        Node(int data, Node* next)
            : data(data)
            , next(next)
        {}
    };

    Node*   head;

    Linked():
        head(nullptr)
    {}
    ~Linked()
    {
        Node* tmp;
        for(;head;head = tmp)
        {
            tmp = head->next;
            delete head;
        }
    }
    ...
```

If we look at `append`. You get the correct test for adding an element to an empty list. But it starts to go wrong in the second half where you are using a loop.

The member `temp` is not initialized. It is also public -- this means it could have been altered since last time you used it. So it is best to use a local variable that you initialize to `head`.

Note: you can also use the `new` constructor for node to reduce code in this function.

```
void Linked::append(int item)
{    
    if (head == nullptr)
    {
        head = new Node(item, nullptr);
    }
    else
    {
        // First find a pointer to the last item in the chain.
        Node* last = head;
        while(last->next)
        {
             last = last->next;
        }
        // Now just add the node.
        last->next = new Node(item, nullptr);


        // Notice this loop happens each time you add an element.
        // This makes adding an element relatively expensive.
        // To avoid this a lot of implementation keep two pointers
        // in the list a `head` and a `tail`. That way data elements
        // can be quickly added to the tail.

        // When you start adding things like delete. 
        // It becomes useful to know your previous element.
        // So it is also very common for the node object to have
        // two pointers `next` and `prev`
     }
```

Note: we always seem to place `nullptr` as the second argument. So we could potentially remove it. But if you try to implement an insert function then it becomes useful:

```
void Linked::insert_at_head(int value)
{
    head = new Node(item, head); // See very useful.
}
```

Not sure what your `traverse` is doing.

```
void linked::traverse()
{       
        Node *trav=start;
        while(trav!=NULL)
        {
                cout<<trav->data<<endl;
                trav=trav->link;
        }

}
```

I would just name that `print`; `traverse` implies going through a tree.

One way to improve the functionality and modularity of `traverse` would be for it to take a parameter of a function that should be applied to all the nodes (but I think that is a bit beyond this exercise). So a couple of things here:

1. Rename to `print`
2. Mark the function as `const`
   It does not alter the state of the object. So it is safe to call on a const version of the object.
3. Printing in C++ is usally done by `operator<<`
   so create one of these that calls your print method.

Like this:

```
void Linked::print(std::ostream& str = std::cout) const // Note const
{       
        Node *trav=start;
        while(trav!=NULL)
        {
                // Added space here so yo can see the <<
                // and what they are applied too.
                //
                // Also prefer "\n" to std::endl (especially in here)
                // The std::endl forces a buffer flush. Doing this
                // after printing every integer becomes very inefficient.
                str << trav->data << "\n";
                trav=trav->next;
        }
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, Linked const& data)
{
     data.print(str);
     return str;
}
```

I think we have now covered enough in one review. I would have another bash at this example. Once you have done that post the code for review again and we can go into some other details.

Comment: Singly linked lists are not supposed to have double pointers, and quite often, they don't have tail pointers either.

Comment: Btw, not only this is a great code review, it's a good tutorial on linked list. You should put this into a blog.

Comment: Actually, slashing all constructors of `node` is superior: Use aggregate-initialization.

Comment: @Deduplicator: What. Can you paste a link?

Comment: If the struct `node` just contains `data` and `next`, nothing else, you can use aggregate-initialization, like `new node{}` for a zeroed node, `new node{42}` for a node with 42 as data and a null next-link, `new node{42, pointer}` if you want to initialize both. I used it in my answer (somewhere far below).

Comment: Naw. I prefer forcing the user to use an explicit initializer.

Comment: In the destructor. Don't we'll use `delete tmp` after the for loop?

Comment: Also in insert_at_head() don't we'll lost the rest of the list if there are some nodes already pointed by head. So do we'll need to save the head before, and then add a node to head and start pointing to the rest of the list with new head->next ?

Comment: `In the destructor. Don't we'll use delete tmp after the for loop?`. Nope. The `head` will be made to point to every value in the chain and delete will be called on it. `tmp` is the next value in the chain. If there is a valid value it will be assigned to head and the loop re-entered.

Comment: `don't we'll lost the rest of the list if there are some nodes already pointed by head`. No. Because head is passed to the constructor of the new node and automatically added as the next in the new node.

Answer (score 4):

### Structure Requirements

Just in a general form, nearly all data structures **require** these three methods:

1. **Insert**
2. **Search/Find**
3. **Delete**

So far, you have **insertion** somewhat, but you are missing some key points:

- You are currently only appending to the tail of the structure. What happens when you want to append at the head of the structure? Or even in between two nodes? You need to define the cases that would allow such an insertion to take place.

---

There is a real lack of functionality to **delete** data that is no longer needed. When considering deletion in linked list, it's important to note the following cases that can take place.

- Deleting the head (first) node
- Deleting a node between two nodes
- Deleting the tail (last) node

Each one of these cases requires different logic.

---

For **Search/Find,** you have the hard part down; traversing the list and checking for null values. But you need to *look for specific data* at some point. Search is pretty simple and it only requires a couple additional lines to your `void linked::traverse()` method.

---

### **Naming Your Methods**

Most of the time you are fine, but it's important to remember that you need to give names that represent what the methods/class/variable does. My main example in this instance is your `void linked::traverse()` method.
While the method *does* traverse the list, it is actually doing more than just going through the list and looking for null values; this method is actively displaying the data. Therefore, I would change this method definition to the following for clarity: `void linked::printAll()` or something along those lines.
I would then make a separate method that is specifically responsible for traversing the list, nothing else. By keeping the responsibilities of each method separate, you'll cut down on debugging time greatly as you extrapolate the structure.

---

### Closing Pointers and Cleanup

This is a ***big one!*** I currently see no attempt to delete pointers, there are also no destructors. Any time you are using an Object-Oriented approach, especially in something such as a data structure, it is imperative that you make sure there are no memory leaks. What happens when this structure gets really big and you have no way to cleanup?
This is the kind of thing that will ruin your data structure as you do some serious testing on it.

---

### Object-Oriented Design

When you are implementing your `linked` class, you should consider which of the following you will need.

- Default constructor (if you wish to instantiate an object with default values)
- Value-accepting constructor (**nearly always**)
- Destructor (If using `new` keyword in your code, you need to delete whatever it is you instantiated at the end of use/program)
- *OPTIONAL* A copy constructor (if using a destructor, this **must** be present)

**EDIT:**
As mentioned by Corbin in the comments, you should consider the rule of 3/5/0 when designing a class. [Rule of Three C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) 
 The **Rule of Three** states that if you are implementing **one or more** of the following methods, you should explicitly define all three.

1. Copy Constructor  `MyObj obj1(obj2);`
2. Copy Assignment operator `obj1 = obj2;` or... `MyObj obj1 = obj2;`
3. Destructor `~linked() { //Cleanup }`
   The **Rule of 5, and Rule of 0** expand on this and more can be found in the link provided above.

Comment: Your "Anytime you design a calss, you need to create a ..." advice applies in this situation, but it's wrong when presented as general rules. Destructors are only required if you're managing some resource (which in modern C++ you very rarely should be) or if you are opening your class to be extended. As for a copy constructor: if you have a destructor you **must** have a copy constructor (even if it's just a private or deleted one). It might be worth throwing something about the rules of 3, 5 and 0 in there.

Comment: Also, your setter/getter seem to have gone Java for a second? And `getData` should be const. And the idiomatic way to do this for a container in C++ would be to return a reference in the non-const version and a const reference in the const version (although `blah.data() = 5;` does look pretty weird, so maybe I'm just trying to over apply iterator patterns).

Comment: Getters/Setters break encapsulation. You are exposing the internal types of your class to the outside world. Methods should be actions that apply to your object. Getters/Setters are popular in languages like Java/C# because they can be used by tooling infrastructures like serializers. Of course there are always exceptions to the rule (that make it a rule). Containers expose there content but in C++ we usually do it via other techniques. Like iterators operator[] etc.

Comment: @Corbin Yeah, I swicthed to java w/o thinking about it :P I'll update it to be C++ once I'm back @ a PC. I'll update my answer with the suggestions you posted also, thanks for those btw.

Comment: @LokiAstari Thanks for pointing this out, I primarily use Java and over-looked this fact in C++. I'll update shortly!

Answer (score 1):

### Naming things

The names you give your classes and variables could be improved. Consider telling a colleague that you "have a linked" in your code (will they understand that?)

I would simply call it "list", "linked_list", or "forward_list" (but not "linked").

Same goes for:

```
node *link;
```

If it is a link, you are better off naming it based on what it points to, not what it is (i.e. call it "next", "next_node", etc).

Also, your traverse function should be called print, dump, display, show or something similar.

### Encapsulation

Your data is erratically set as public or private; This seems (to me) to follow no rules. Instead of creating a `node` as a public class (although you will not use it outside of the `linked` class) and making `linked` a friend, consider making it a private structure of the `linked` class: the friend declaration dissapears, everything will be public to list, and private to the outside world.

Similarly, the data in the `linked` class should be private.

### List Operations

Your public interface for the list is inadequate for any purpose except printing the elements to the output stream.

Common scenarios for a list are:

- insertion in various positions;
- iterating the elements;
- FIFO processing (you will need iteration support);
- checking for emptyness;
- reading the list size;
- modifying values;
- removing elements;
- removing all elements (that is, clearing the list);

For size and emptyness checks, you should consider caching the list size.

For iteration you should implement either iterators, or the visitor pattern, or both.

### Code Style

- consider using `nullptr` instead of `NULL`
- optimize code for ease of writing client code instead of ease of writing implementation:

  ```
  ptr = new node();
  ptr->data=item;
  ```

  This should be a single line, looking like this:

  ```
  ptr = new node{ item };
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Well, something a bit different:

1. As Loki Astari already said, don't use `using namespace std;`. That actually holds for *any* `namespace`, unless you know exactly what symbols that might import, now and in the future, and are absolutely sure that's what you want/need.
2. A better name for a single-linked-list would be `slist`.
3. As no `node` is ever exposed by the `slist`, and the `slist` needs full access, `node` should be a `struct` with everything public.
4. As all the behavior is in the `slist`, `node` doesn't need any member-variables. And as aggregate-initialization is perfectly adequate, it also shouldn't have any explicitly declared constructors.
5. Because `node` is an implementation-detail of `slist` without any behavior which could be fruitfully shared, it should not be exposed to any other code.
   Make it a private member.

   The private member-struct of `slist`:

   ```
   struct node {
       int data;
       struct node* link;
   };
   ```
6. `slist` also has some useless members, namely `ptr` and `temp`. What are they for? Slash them.
7. It's missing a destructor that cleans everything up:

   ```
   ~slist() {
       for(node* head = start, *next; head; head = next) {
           next = head->link;
           delete head;
       }
   }
   ```
8. Its implicit default-ctor is fine, because it picks up the member-initializer for `start`. Still, when we fix the other constructors, it needs to be explicitly declared or it will be suppressed:

   ```
   slist() = default;
   ```
9. The other constructors are just bad and need to be explicitly replaced:

   ```
   slist(linked&& x) : start(x.start) { x.start = 0; }
   slist(const linked& x) {
       for(node** target = &start, source = x.start; source; source = source->link) {
           *target = new node {source.data};
           target = &target[0]->link;
       }
   }
   ```
10. Throwing in how to enable use of initializer-lists here:

    ```
    slist(std::initializer_list<int> l) {
        node** target = &start;
        for(auto x : l) {
            *target = new node {x};
            target = &target[0]->link;
        }
    }
    ```
11. Now we just need a method to swap two `slist`s:

    ```
    void swap(slist& x) { std::swap(start, x.start); }
    ```
12. And assignment is easily done thanks to the copy-and-swap-idiom:

    ```
    slist& operator=(slist x) { swap(x); return *this; }
    ```
13. `append(int item)` currently pushes some of its temporaries into the class? Well, cannot have that. Aside from that, the function is far more complex than needed.

    ```
    void append(int item) {
        node** target = &start;
        while(*target)
            target = &target[0]->link;
        *target = new node{item};
    }
    ```
14. `traverse` should accept the output-stream as an argument, though it *can* default to `std::cout`. Also, it *should not* needlessly repeatedly flush the stream. And that's a good place for a `for`-loop:

    ```
    void traverse(std::ostream& o = std::cout) {
        for(node* p = start; p; p = p->link)
            o << p->data << '\n';
    }
    ```

Comment: Why do you need pointer on pointer and what is `&target[0]->link`?

Comment: I'm using `node**` to avoid unnesseccary special-cases. And `&target[0]->link` is the address of the member `link` of the structure the pointer `target` points to points to.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the special cases you try to avoid? I had difficulty parsing your expression. My first attempt was `*(&(*target)).link`. Is it equivalent to `&((*(*target)).link)` (if I correctly understand the operators precedence page)?

Comment: @greendiod The last one it is. And the special case would be assigning the head-pointer in contrast to some link-pointer.